# Rouché for Polynomial $p(z)=z^7+z(z-3)^3+1$ around non-centered annulus.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

> Let $p(z)=z^7+z(z-3)^3+1$. Find the numbers of zeros (including multiplicities) in $B_{1}(3)$.

I want to apply Rouché's Theorem for $p(z)$ and $g(z)=-z(z-3)^3$, but I don't know how to confine on $|z-3|=1$. The problem should be solved without using a calculator.

Advice appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to work with unit circle $|z|\leqslant1$, For this purpose let $w=z-3$ then $p(z)=(w+3)^7+w^4+3w^3+1$ and for $|w|=1$ we have
$$|f(w)|=|w^4+3w^3+1|\leqslant|w|^4+3|w|^3+1=5<|w+3|^7=|g(w)|$$
therefore the number of zeros $p(w)$ and $g(w)$ in $|w|\leqslant1$ are the same, but $g(w)$ has no zeros there.

Answer (score 1):

You get
$$
|z^7-1|\ge 2^7-1=127
$$
and
$$
|z(z-3)^3|\le 4
$$
on the circle $|z-3|=1$. Thus $p$ has the same number of roots inside the circle as $z^7+1$.

---

Roots of $z^7+\alpha z(z-3)^3+1$ for $α\in[0,1]$, red for $α=1$.
[image]

Comment: I thought of this, too. However, I could not come up with a way to account for the number of zeros that $z^7+1$ actually has within $|z-3| \leq 1$ without using a calculator or graphing tool.

Comment: As $0=z^7+1$ implies $|z|=1$, all roots are on the unit circle around $0$ and thus well outside the unit circle around $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q(z) = z^7.$ Then on the circle $z= 3 +e^{it}, 0\le t \le 2\pi,$

$$|p(z)-q(z)| = |z(z-3)^3 +1| \le |z(z-3)^3| +1 \le 4\cdot 1^3 + 1 = 5 .$$

But note $|q|\ge 2^7$ on this circle. Since $5< 2^7,$ $p,q,$ have the same number of zeros in $D(3,1).$ Since $q=0$ has no zeroes in this disc, $p$ has no zeros in this disc by Rouche.